# ¿Por qué esta variable debe contener false?

Tags: php

Estoy aprendiendo php desde hace poco y me gustaría entender bien su funcionamiento.
 Tengo el siguiente código que sirve para limitar los usuarios con el mismo nombre a 1 en un formulario de registro.

```
 $statement = $conexion -> prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario LIMIT 1');
    $statement -> execute(array(':usuario' => $usuario));

    $resultado = $statement->fetch();

    if($resultado != false){
        $errores .= '<li>el nombre de usuario ya existe</li>';
    }
```

En caso de que no exista el usuario la variable $resultado devolvería false. Pueden explicarme de una forma "para doomies" ¿qué operaciones se realizan en cada paso para que $resultado devuelva false?

Muchas gracias

Comment: `if($resultado != false){` esto es porque el `$statement->fetch(` retorna un  valor que lo combierte directamente en `true` y si no se toma como que es `0` o `false` por ende al poner `!=` niegas que sea `false` puede hacerse igual con `if($resultado)`

Comment: La respuesta aceptada es excelente, porque te explica paso por paso el funcionamiento de cada cosa. Pero hay otras buenas prácticas que te recomendaría para este caso. 1. Es mejor usar `COUNT` cuando se trata de verificar existencia de datos: `SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario`. Se podría creer que `LIMIT 1` es más rápido, pero no lo es. Además, tienes otra ventaja: la posibilidad de saber cuántos registros hay realmente.  2. Si te decides por esta consulta, dado que devuelve una sola columna, sería mejor usar `fetchColumn` en vez de `fetch`

Comment: @A.Cedano muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

en pocas palabras:

Primero:

```
$statement = $conexion -> prepare('SELECT ...');
```

En esta línea estas declarando un manejador de sentencias llamado `$statement`, esto lo haces usando un objeto de conexión llamado `$conexion` y aplicándole el método `prepare` que recibe como parámetro tu consulta SQL.

Segundo:

```
$statement -> execute(array(':usuario' => $usuario));
```

En esta línea simplemente ejecutas la sentencia que has preparado previamente, y le pasas como argumento (le 'bindeas') la variable `$usuario`, de esta forma tu sentencia SQL se completa al usar la variable `$usuario` para realizar la consulta.

Tercero:

```
$resultado = $statement->fetch();
```

En esta línea se captura el resultado de la consulta realizada anteriormente. La función `fetch` devuelve un booleano, `true` en caso de éxito (la consulta generó un resultado) o `false` (la consulta no generó resultado, no hay datos), o devuelve `null` en caso que la consulta no posea más filas (datos) o los datos se truncaron. Este valor es almacenado en la variable `$resultado`.

Por último:

```
if($resultado != false){
    $errores .= '<li>el nombre de usuario ya existe</li>';
}
```

Aqui simplemente mostramos el mensaje en caso que el usuario ya exista. ¿Cómo sabemos que el usuario ya existe?, porque nuestra variable `$result` es `true`, y eso significa que `fectch()` devolvió `true`.

Tal vez yo cambiaría la sentencia `if` por la siguiente:

```
if($resultado){
    $errores .= '<li>el nombre de usuario ya existe</li>';
}
```

De esta manera tal vez está más claro.

Espero que eso aclare tu duda.

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias Mauricio, ahora me ha quedado bien claro

:)

Answer (score 0):

Pues veamos por parte que esta haciendo:
aqui esta trayendo solo un registro en donde el usuario de la base de datos sea = al usuario que le estas pasando:

```
$statement = $conexion -> prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario LIMIT 1');
$statement -> execute(array(':usuario' => $usuario));
```

aqui `if($resultado != false){` esta preguntando que si el usuario es distinto de false(es decir, que si el usuario existe) se ira false, es decir, no existe, pero en caso contrario, de que exista sera true y entrara al IF y dira que el nombre de usuario ya existe.

en resumen: para que esta operacion se cumpla, el usuario indicado no debe existir en la base de datos, de lo contrario no entrara en el IF.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta